# MySQL: How to Join to first row

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables, **Master** with other two **TableA** and **TableB**, and **Master** has both one to many relationship with the other two tables.

What I want is to get all master records associated with only the latest record from both TableA and TableB, so I use left joins as below,

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
Master master
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ta.* FROM TableA ta WHERE ta.masterId = master.id LIMIT 1 ORDER BY ta.id DESC ) as tableA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tb.* FROM TableB tb WHERE tb.masterId = master.id LIMIT 1 ORDER BY tb.id DESC ) as tableB
WHERE master.status = 1
```

However above sql statement hit an error,

```
Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'ta' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
; bad SQL grammar ... Table 'ta' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause
```

It complains `.. in global ORDER clause`, but it doesn't seem like that, all order clauses are used in the subquery?

Where is wrong with my sql, it might be naive but is there a better way to achieve my requirement?

Loads of thanks.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch last record of tablea, tableb for each `masterId` first, then  `left join` tablea and tableb to get all the records:

```
select m.*, ta.*, tb.*
from master m
left join (
    select tablea.*
    from tablea
    join (select max(id) as id from tablea group by masterId) tmp
    on tablea.id = tmp.id
) ta on ta.masterId = m.id
left join (
    select tableb.*
    from tableb
    join (select max(id) as id from tableb group by masterId) tmp
    on tableb.id = tmp.id
) tb on tb.masterId = m.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LIMIT 1` AND `ORDER BY` clauses should switch places

Comment: Yes... I switched them but seems that didn't solve the problem